# Axes ButtonDownFcn not being executed when plot object is selected

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, mouseclick-event

I am creating a real time MATLAB demo and I need to select a point of interest by clicking on the `axes`. In general, the system works fine and I am able to modify the variables using the `ButtonDownFcn`. However the following problem occurs

When I plot other data (such as a scatter plot) on the same axis, the `ButtonDownFcn` does not seem to be triggered if I click on the scatter plot rather than the `axes` where there is no plot. There are no errors.

This is an issue because my scatter plots can be quite dense and the point I would like to click on lies underneath of the plot object.

How can I make it so that all mouse clicks are registered by the `axes` so that my `ButtonDownFcn` gets executed on every click.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The line also has a button click callback. You might want to disable that.  I think there's a 'hittest' property you can turn off (set enabled to false).

Answer (score 1):

You want to utilize the [`HitTest` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html#property_hittest) to disable the ability of all other graphics objects to respond to a mouse click.

If you want to only enable clicks on the `axes` something like this should work.

```
% Disable callbacks for all objects within the current axes
set(findall(gca), 'HitTest', 'off')

% Enable click events for the axes and set the buttondownfcn
set(gca, 'HitTest', 'on', 'ButtonDownFcn', callback)
```